# Making clickable area of button match the button and moving arrow up to center inside

Tags: css

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-currying-h7c3r?file=/styles.css

.line and .arrow are the classes you want probably. Click create event and you see how the arrows are too low, and the clickable area is below the actual button as well as on the button. It even goes outside of the main div, which is #secondPage.

For the clickable area, I can't find anything about reducing it.

For centering text I tried this as well as a few other display: table-cell and text-align: center way. https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/50c29d469bc1e14c8b001f64

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do?
https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-mclean-9ph0g?file=/styles.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @secret This is happening because of the fixed height of button,

I made few changes in your CSS you can try with this one it's help you

```
.arrow {
    border-radius: 2vh;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: darkblue;
    width: 5vh;
    height: 2vh;
    line-height: 0; /* 1. Change Line Height otherwise you want to remove height */
    padding: 10px 0; /* 2. TOP - BOTTOM spacing */
    cursor: pointer; /* 3. Show cursor this is clickeble */
}
```

I hope It's Help You :) Thanks

Comment: Thanks, how do I make the buttons in the vertical middle of the box they are in? And how do I make the clickable area just on the buttons?

Comment: How do I make the size of the height bigger within its box? I cant do it without increasing the size of the box its in.

Comment: You can do it with increasing padding size.

Comment: That seems to increase the size of the big box the button is in but not the button itself.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs because your button has a fixed height, but the font-size is bigger in some screens. In order to fix this you should change your font-size and height to use the same metrics (e.g. both px,em,rem,vh etc) and make sure that the font-size will always be less than your height.

Things to remember when adjusting those two:

1. Padding also consumes some of your height
2. Line height must not be less than your font-size.